# how to replace and update mongoose schema

Tags: mongoose

Hi I have a User schema I just want to update and replace it
here's the example
I have a followUsers schema like

```
followUser: [
_id:String
]
```

I'd like to replace it

```
followUser: [
_id:String;
username:String;
profileImage:String;
]
```

the problem is that my website already has users and users have following users
is there a way to replace the schema and update it?
thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method of getting the follower object in the user database is not correct, and you have to make complex queries to discuss updates and make queries. It would be better to have a separate follow database.
To solve your problem, the best way to write a script is to find all the users and create a separate function that will create the array you want and save it in that user. You can use Promis.all() for this.
for example:

```
        User.find({}) 
             .then((users)=> {  
                 Promise.all(users.map(user => {
                 
                  return updateFollowerArray(user)
                })) })
```